# Using Pycharm IDE for Python, unused variables

Tags: pycharm

It used to be the case that when I did not use a variable in Pycharm, the IDE editor would make the variable appear gray.  That feature is gone now and I cannot get it back.  Does anyone know how to get this feature back?

Comment: don't forget the "reader mode" in that mode pycharm does not analyze your code even if the preference settings are right.

Answer (score 5):

In the Settings open Editor -> Inspections. In the list in the middle open the python category and look for "Unused local" (it is sorted alphabetically). That should be checked.

Also check your color settings in case the variable simply doesn't get highlighted the way you want it.

Comment: And the color settings for an unused local? Or maybe the inspection is switched off altogether? Are any other errors highlighted, PEP8 notices shown, etc?

Comment: Which PyCharm version are you using? I tried on 2016.1.3 EAP and found, to my surprise, that I get the same thing. It's supposed to emit a "weak warning" which not only changes the color, but also in the "Analysis complete" popup.

Comment: On Pycharm 5.0.4 its working. Maybe they broke it? If so, a bug report for Jetbrains would be the right thing to do.

Comment: Are you sure you are doing a *local* variable, meaning, inside a block such as a function? The "Unused Local Variable" intention does not flag global variables.

Comment: @PaulEveritt this is correct. At the same time I cannot find an option for "unused global" which seems to be the crux of this question.

Comment: don't forget the "reader mode" in that mode pycharm does not analyze your code even if the preference settings are right.

Answer (score 3):

As [@TehSphinX mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36724299/4298200), the Editor -> Inspections settings is where it is. Use the search bar.

Also, perhaps as important: don't forget the "reader mode" in that mode pycharm does not analyze your code even if the preference settings are right.

Comment: This worked for me, if Pycharm is in Reader mode even if the Inspection variable is checked, the unused variables will not change color. Tested on arguments of a function. thanks.

Comment: How to enable/disable Reader mode:

File | Settings | Editor | Reader Mode (Windows and Linux)
PyCharm | Preferences | Editor | Reader Mode (macOS)

Enable Reader mode: use this checkbox to enable or disable the option.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if you have added an interpreter for your project. If no, then add one interpreter, and it should work now.
2. Go to Editor -> Inspections settings and check the box for unused variables.